# Azure App Service and .NET Framework 4.8 version

Tags: .net, azure

In the Azure App Service portal, I can't be replacing ASP.NET V4.7 with the .NET Framework V4.8 version drop-down under General Settings in the Configuration blade.
If anyone can help and tell me how to update to the Azure App Service .NET Framework to .NET Framework V4.8.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/06/09/NET-Framework-4.8-is-coming-to-App-Service.html
This post explains when you will be able to update to .NET framework 4.8.

Comment: Hi, I did all these steps and the .NET framework 4.8 is installed on the server, but in the drop-down, under General Settings in the Configuration, I can not select the .NET framework 4.8 version.